# Visual studio 15 enterprise is not executing the loaded project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The visual studio 15 enterprise says that "the program cant start because MSVCP100D.dll is missing from your computer" when i load a project and run the test. The program was running perfectly on VS 2010 Ultimate and the program executed perfectly and showed the desired output but after i installed VS 2015 this error is coming. i am using VS for computer graphics using OGL.  What should i do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Something in your program has a dependency on debug dlls, besides there is insufficient information for us to help you, you need to determine what has this dependency

Comment: Have you tried re-installing VS? Anyway, imho this does not really belong here.

Comment: the program was running perfectly on VS 2010 Ultimate and the program executed perfectly and showed the desired output  but after i installed VS 2015 this error is coming. i am using VS for computer graphics using OGL.

Comment: Are you re-compiling the program? That DLL is from VS2010 but should not be a dependency if you compile from VS2015.